# Flanker: MimePart is not iterable

Tags: python, email, parsing

I'm a noob and using Flanker to parse emails.
https://github.com/mailgun/flanker

I'm getting a Not Iterable error that I just can't seem to figure out.  I've read tons of pages about lists, but I just can't get it to work.  I'm hopeful I can get some help.

To run the following code, you will need to install Flanker, and save this file as 'email'.
http://pastebin.com/ZS4q2kYN

I'm trying to read the 'attachmenttype' and do something depending on the response.  Can't get it to work though.  Here is the test code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#Open Email
from flanker import mime
with open ("email", mode="rb") as myfile:
    message_string=myfile.read()
myfile.close()

#Read Email
msg = mime.from_string(message_string)

#read attachment type
attachmenttype = msg.parts[1]
print attachmenttype

#This errors for me:  TypeError: argument of type 'MimePart' is not iterable
if attachmenttype:
    if '(text/html)' in attachmenttype:
        print "woohoo"
```

Here is the response I get:
[image: myerror]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`attachmenttype` may be printed a string but it is not a string,more a structure containing some properties. However, since you can print it, you're halfway there. Just convert it to a string using `str` and compare that.

Fix your code like this. I couldn't test it but I don't see how it wouldn't work:

```
if attachmenttype:
    if '(text/html)' in str(attachmenttype):
        print("woohoo")
```

Comment: OMG THANK YOU!  I spent all day yesterday on that, and then most of the day on Friday.  Wow... Thank you for your quick reply

Comment: Can you explain why that is not a string?

Comment: it is an object that has a lot of methods. For instance, text and html are separate attributes of this class, concatenated by the conversion to string.